# Executing a SQL Server SP from VBA - Arguments Error

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, vb6

I'm getting the error "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another" while trying to call a SQL Server stored procedure from Excel/VBA.

Can't figure out how to call from VBA?

**Stored Procedure Parameters**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Productivity_GetIndividuals] (
@startDate DATE,
@endDate DATE)
....
```

**VBA Code**

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandText = "sp_Productivity_GetIndividuals"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@startDate", adDate, adParamInput, , "3/1/2014")
     .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@endDate", adDate, adParamInput, , "3/31/2014")
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = .Execute
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing your dates as "2014-03-01" and it will work. If you start with an excel date parameter, use `FORMAT` to convert to string, as in:

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@startDate", adDate, adParamInput, , Format(now(),"yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

Comment: I changed the code to the below, but I still get the exact same error.

Comment: Sorry for last post (I'm a rookie on formatting).  I changed the code to the suggestion but I get the exact error.

Comment: What if you try `.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@startDate", adDate, adParamInput, , "2014-03-31")`?